# C# - One Interface, two implementations: How to redirect a method call from one implementation to another?

Tags: c#, interface

I have two implementations with the same name for my interface as follows:

```
interface IDBCaller
{ 
    IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList();
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

//First implementation of IDBCaller in project1  
class DBCaller : IDBCaller
{

    public IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return new List<User>();
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        //doing something
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //doing something
    }
}
//Second implementation of IDBCaller in project2 
class DBCaller: IDBCaller
{

    public IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return null; //Currently returns null but the desire state is to call the RetrieveUserList in Implementation1 from project 1
    }
    public void Method1()
    {
         //doing something
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
         //doing something
    }
}
```

Implementation 1 and 2 have the same `RetrieveUserList()` method. 
When the `RetrieveUserList()` is called from **Implementation 2**, I want the call to be redirected to the same method in **Implementation 1**.

Comment: So you have two different classes with the same name? Or two different classes which implement `IDBCaller`? If the `RetrieveUserList()` method is the same in both `Implementation 1` and `Implemenation 2` why would you need to call it from the other class? Need more information, this is confusing.

Comment: If you need this sort of calling, it would make sense to create a base class with the base functionality for the method.  Then inherit from this.  You can then override the method if needed or have it call the method on the base class or both

Comment: It's a complex thing that I tried to simplify. The RetrieveUserList from implementation 2 does not contain any code. The code is located in Implementation 1 and I would like to redirect the call there. The two implementations are located in different parts of the solution and are doing things differently.

Comment: @Yandroide Then you would want to do as bhmahler suggested and create a `base class` which would be `Implementation 1` and have `Implementation 2` `inherit` from the `base class` and call the method `RetrieveUserList()` of `base`.

Comment: If you're trying to share code between 2 distinct implementations of an interface, then there is either a common base between them or you have a nasty code smell.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use inheritance e.g:

```
interface IDBCaller
{ 
    IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList();
}

class Implementation1 : IDBCaller
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return new List<User>();
    }
}

class Implementation2 : Implementation1
{
    public override IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return base.RetrieveUserList();
    }
}
```

Or use a base class with the RetrieveUserList implementation

```
interface IDBCaller
{ 
    IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList();
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

class ImplementationBase
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return new List<User>();
    }

}
class Implementation1 : ImplementationBase, IDBCaller
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Implementation2 : ImplementationBase, IDBCaller
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the correct structure based on the OP's requirements. +1

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Jens said, you could use the decorator pattern.

```
public interface IDBCaller
{ 
    IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList();
}

public class Implementation1 : IDBCaller
{
    public IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return new List<User>();
    }
}

public class Implementation2 : IDBCaller
{
    IDBCaller decoratedImplementation;

    public Implementation2(IDBCaller decoratedImplementation)
    {
        this.decoratedImplementation = decoratedImplementation;
    }


    public IEnumerable<User> RetrieveUserList()
    {
        return this.decoratedImplementation.RetrieveUserList();
    }
}
```